# how to set link /profile/username in .htaccess

Tags: php, .htaccess

i'm working on a script and I want to make the links such as www.mysite.com/signup. this link for registration. www.mysite.com/user/username and this link for user's profile. the links without any php extension. also when someone request link such as www.mysite.com/signup.php should redirect him to www.mysite.com/signup

.my .htaccess

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^/?([a-z]+)$ $1.php [L]
```

with this, all links are working fine, but when I access the user's profile such as
www.mystie.com/profile/username

I get this error

Object not found!

The requested URL was not found on this server. If you entered the URL manually please check your spelling and try again.

If you think this is a server error, please contact the webmaster.

Error 404

my question: what code to add to let that link works fine?

thank you

Answer (score 1):

Your routing requests blindly to php files, this doesn't have anything to do with your issue:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule ^/?([a-z]+)$ $1.php [L]
```

Now you need to add a rule to route profiles, since you don't have a rule for it, your profile links aren't going to work. So something that looks like:

```
RewriteRule ^/?profile/(.*)$ /profile.php?username=$1 [L]
```

Replacing `profile.php` with whatever script generates profiles and the `username=` with whatever _GET param the script looks for for the username.

Comment: what I should add in profile.php to get username? I only have this code. $username = @$_SESSION['username'];

Comment: @KhaledBawazir So instead of `$username = @$_SESSION['username'];`, you'd pull it out of the GET variable `$_GET['username']`

Comment: profile.php `<?php
session_start();
require 'connect.php';
require_once 'core/classes/user_class.php';
require_once 'core/functions/main.php';
include 'inc/top.php';
include 'inc/header.php';

if(isset($_GET['username'])) {
    $username = $_GET['username'];
} else {
    $username = 'defaultUser';
}

echo $username;
include 'inc/footer.php';

?>`

Comment: .htaccess `RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule ^/?([a-z]+)$ $1.php [L]
RewriteRule ^/?profile/(.*)$ /profile.php?username=$1 [L]
` and still doesn't work

Comment: `$_GET['username']` now it works with me. but not like www.mysite.com/profile/username

Answer (score 1):

Ok I solved the problem

big thanks to all who tried to help me and especially Jon Lin :)

this is the code

```
RewriteEngine On 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d 
RewriteRule ^profile/(.*)$ profile.php?username=$1 [L]
```

my profile.php

```
$username = $_GET['username'];

$info = fetchUserInfo($username);

echo $info['username'];
echo $info['userid'];
```

hope also help some people having same problem

Answer (score 0):

You want to read in the manual for mod_rewrite about the two directives 'RewriteLog' and 'RewriteLogLevel'. Using those you can learn to understand how the rewriting engine processes the requests by seeing all steps in a log file.